# Can i get IMEI no from Mobile Devices using PHP

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, android-studio

Is there any way to retrieve an IMEI number from a mobile device when it is connected to your website?!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, IMEI is not transmitted via http requests.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. IMEI is not made available to webpages.